# No me imprime en el archivo lo que quiero fgets()

Tags: c

Al principio fgets() no me funcionaba correctamente (o eso creia) y lei en uno de estos foros que la solucion era poner fgets() , pero al imprimir los valores que quiero que ponga en el txt , me pone los 100 huecos del string con obviamente simbolos raros , lo que quiero que haga es que simplemente coja lo que le pone el usuario en el programa.

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void abrirfichero(char A,char B[],char C,char D[100],FILE *fichero){
      do{
            printf("Escribe si quieres que sea de entrada o salida:");
            scanf("%c",&A);

            if (A=='E'){
                printf("HOla");
            }
            else if(A=='S'){
                printf("Escribe el nombre del archivo:");
                scanf("%s",B);
                fichero = fopen(B, "r");
                if (fichero==NULL) {
                      perror("No puedo abrir el fichero");
                }
                else {
                   printf("He podido abrir el fichero.\n");
                } 

                fseek( fichero, 0, SEEK_END );
                if (ftell( fichero ) != 0 )
                {
                    printf("Quieres borrar el archivo? S/N:"); //Aqui es el problema//
                    scanf(" %c",&C);

                    if(C=='S'){
                          fclose(fichero);
                          fichero = fopen(B, "w");
                          printf("Escribe lo que quieres poner: ");
                          fgets(D,100,stdin);
                          fgets(D,100,stdin);
                          fwrite(D , 1 , 100 , fichero );

                    }
                    else if(C=='N'){
                        // codigo
                    }
                }

            }

      } while(A!='E' && A!='S');
}

void main(){
    char A,B[20],C,D[100];
    FILE *fichero;
    abrirfichero(A,B,C,D,fichero);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No tienes que llamar dos veces a `fgets` sino asegurarte de limpiar el buffer antes de pedir información. Limpiarlo puede ser tan sencillo como eliminar el salto de línea que se quedó ahí de la última lectura:

```
fgetc(stdin);
fgets(D, 100, stdin);
```

Por otro lado, entiendo que no pretendes guardar los 100 caracteres que tiene de capacidad `D`, sino únicamente aquellos con información útil ... para eso usa `fprintf` en vez de `fwrite` o `fputs`:

```
fprintf(fichero, "%s", D);

fputs(D, fichero);
```

Y con esto ya estaría.

Nota que tu función no espera recibir ningun valor de `main`, luego lo suyo sería que movieses la declaración de todas las variables a tu función, en vez de pasar argumentos de forma totalmente innecesaria.

Si ya además usases nombres con sentido para las variables, mejor aún!!!

```
void abrirfichero(void)
{
    char A /* mejor "opcion" */,
         B[20] /* nombreArchivo ?? */,
         C /* opcion2 */,
         D[100] /* datosUsuario */;
    FILE *fichero;

    // ...
}
```

Recuerda que puedes declarar las variables en casi cualquier momento, no es necesario declararlas todas al inicio. Esta práctica mejora la seguridad y la legibilidad del programa.

```
void abrirfichero(void)
{
    char opcion;

    do{
        printf("Escribe si quieres que sea de entrada o salida:");
        scanf("%c",&opcion);

        if (opcion=='E'){
            printf("HOla");
        }
        else if(opcion=='S'){
            char nombreArchivo[20];
            printf("Escribe el nombre del archivo:");
            scanf("%s",nombreArchivo);
            FILE * fichero = fopen(nombreArchivo, "r");
            if (fichero==NULL) {
                  perror("No puedo abrir el fichero");
            }
            else {
               printf("He podido abrir el fichero.\n");
            } 

            fseek( fichero, 0, SEEK_END );
            if (ftell( fichero ) != 0 )
            {
                printf("Quieres borrar el archivo? S/N:"); //Aqui es el problema//
                char respuesta;
                scanf(" %c",&respuesta);

                if(respuesta=='S'){
                      fclose(fichero);
                      fichero = fopen(nombreArchivo, "w");
                      printf("Escribe lo que quieres poner: ");

                      char respuestaUsuario[100];
                      getc(stdin); // Descartamos el salto de linea
                      fgets(respuetaUsuario, 100, stdin);
                      fputs(respuestaUsuario, fichero);

                }
                else if(respuesta=='N'){
                    // codigo
                }
            }
        }
    } while(opcion!='E' && opcion!='S');
}
```